# Webpack with bower support

Tags: angularjs, bower, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Would I like to load preferably the node packages, and only if not exist, loads the bower package.

> I would just use the node package only as recommended in Webpack site, but I need to load a library that is just in bower, https://github.com/Stamplay/stamplay-js-sdk  and    https://github.com/Stamplay/angular-stamplay

### Try with [bower-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/lpiepiora/bower-webpack-plugin)

I installed https://github.com/lpiepiora/bower-webpack-plugin

But when I run `webpack-dev-server -d --watch` the error is displayed in chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module is not a function(anonymous function) @ app.js:8__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 6cecf8d96fb5a1205f10:19(anonymous function) @ bootstrap 6cecf8d96fb5a1205f10:39__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 6cecf8d96fb5a1205f10:19(anonymous function) @ bootstrap 6cecf8d96fb5a1205f10:39(anonymous function) @ bootstrap 6cecf8d96fb5a1205f10:39
angular.js:68Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

### Try with ResolverPlugin (see [Webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-bower.html))

In webpack.config i add..

```
plugins: [
     ...
    , new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Q: 'q',
        store: 'store.js',
        Stamplay: 'stamplay-js-sdk'
    })
    , new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
        [
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
        ], ["normal", "loader"]
    )

],
....
resolve: {
    root: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')
    ],
```

But, like mention [here](https://github.com/Stamplay/stamplay-js-sdk/issues/15) the `Stamplay` object is not correct!

### Trying with CDN and angular-webpack-plugin

First add script tag into `index.html` ..

Second, add externals in webpack.config ..

```
externals: {
    stamplay: 'Stamplay'
},
```

And finally .. `new AngularPlugin` into `plugins` on webpack.config

This way, worsks **but** I cant use `angular-stamplay`, when I try, a error in module `stamplay` apper. :(

See branch with [this change here](https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpackBowerStarter/tree/stamplay_in_cdn)

The full project is here: https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpackBowerStarter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, tried your project from git https://github.com/Ridermansb/webpackBowerStarter

And as mentioned at https://github.com/lpiepiora/bower-webpack-plugin/issues/20 I too had that `Cannot resolve module 'stamplay-js-sdk'` issue , then in webpackBowerStarter directory I did `bower install stamplay-js-sdk` then `sudo npm run build` and voila! It was done.

On `npm run start` which is same as `webpack-dev-server -d --watch` I get http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/ like
[image: http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/]
And console says 
[image]

sry if u meant something else. Does this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Hi @aishwat, something is wrong ..
even in your screenshot, you can see that there is no `init` function in `Stamplay` object.    In [stamplay-js-sdk](https://github.com/Stamplay/stamplay-js-sdk) docs, this function exist.    Even if you expand the object details, you see that this is not a Stamplay object.     Check the issue https://github.com/Stamplay/stamplay-js-sdk/issues/15

Comment: ok if i do a simple `<script src="https://drrjhlchpvi7e.cloudfront.net/libs/stamplay-js-sdk/1.3.1/stamplay.min.js"></script>` at `index.html`  `Stamplay.init("APPID"); ` at index.html works but without it it doesn't.

AND from stamplay.js i can get `function(win){ })` objects get attached because it's at global/window scope `Function('return this')()` .However just next function `(function (root) {})(this) ` doesn't append init to Stamplay because it's in `this` context

Comment: one lame fix , in stamplay.js before `;(function(win){` define `var that` then set `that=store` inside `;(function(win){` then in `(function (root) {` put `that.init=root.Stamplay.init;` then u get `Stamplay.init` working.
I don't know what u want to do with init :D

Comment: Thanks .. I will try it.  I would just use the `Stamplay` object as [in the documentation](https://stamplay.com/docs/jssdk#intro-install) :)    Not only `Stamplay.init("APPID");` but all apis for `Stamplay` object..  like `new Stamplay.Cobject('dinner').Model;`

Comment: @Ridermansb but it wasn't working so y accept ? did u get some fix ?

Comment: The problem is in how the StamplaySDK exposes its api.
The Webpack side is configured correctly, so I decided to accept your answer. I [opened a issue on github](https://github.com/Stamplay/stamplay-js-sdk/issues/15) about this problem.